# Migrating from MongoDB 2.6 to 3.2. Can we skip 3.0 for data?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

When upgrading from MongoDB 2.6 [to MongoDB 3.2](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.2-upgrade/#upgrade-standalone-mongod-instance-to-mongodb-3-2), documentation dictates to upgrade to MongoDB 3.0 first.

Is this for data conversion? Is a MongoDB 2.6 `mongodump` compatible with the MongoDB 3.2 `mongorestore`?

I.e. does this work?

- Running MongoDB `2.6`
- `mongodump -v --dumpDbUsersAndRoles`
- drop collections
- (upgrade to MongoDB `3.0`)
- upgrade to MongoDB `3.2`
- `mongorestore`

Mainly I'd like to know if we can import 2.6 dumps into 3.2, and for a better understanding I'd like to know if without data (and if so, *why*) the upgrade to 3.0 is necessary.

**-update-**

There are changes in indexes and users/roles.

`mongodump` does not include indexes, so we are safe there. Are we safe with users/roles (`--dumpDbUsersAndRoles`)?

Answer (score 1):

There is a big changeSef 2.6 --> 3.0 [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.0-compatibility/) and 3.0 --> 3.2 [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.2-compatibility/)
The biggest change for me is WiredTiger,

As this list is huge, there is no specific reason, why we need to go via 3.0 to 3.2. 
There were changes regarding indexes (including geo ones), so this could be a reason to use middle step.

If you have enough resources - I could suggest to restore directly into 3.2 and see the results (I will give this a go if I will be in similar position),

To fix indexing issues when restoring - you could delete index data from metadata file.

Comment: Upvoted for now. The upgrade is pending. I will see what happens. Mongodump does not include index data so it will be rebuilt anyway. Big question is if users and roles will be correctly handled.